# Copy files using Server Side Copy/Clone in Python?

Tags: python, performance, filesystems, file-copying, btrfs

Protocols like [Samba](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Server-Side_Copy) and AFP support server side copy of files. The BTRFS file system even supports instant server side clone operations that don't take up space.

- Windows Explorer, Robocopy and MacOS Finder already utilize this
- [Cloner](https://github.com/djwong/xfstests/blob/master/src/cloner.c) is a sample implementation within xfstests
- Here is a video showing it in action in [Explorer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFSjXoHg_Z4)

Overall it's an amazing feature and yet many copy tools including file copy in Python doesn't make use of it yet.

Is there an implementation of it already in Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I actually found an implementation for Py2 & Py3 that does exactly that.
It's called [Python Reflinks](https://reflink.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html)